# Terrain detail grass not receiving shadow

Tags: unity, shadows, terrain-rendering

The grass painted onto my terrain is in the shadow area of the house wall, but they're not receiving shadows. Why does this happen?

[image: 3D scene of a house, grassy terrain, and trees]

[image: Terrain painting inspector]

[image: Terrain settings inspector]

[image: Grass texture import settings]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of the Grass01A *prefab* object that's referenced in your terrain detail settings? (Not the import settings for the texture of the same name)

Comment: @DMGregory added!

Comment: That's a material, not a prefab. In the terrain painting tool, where it says "Detail Prefab", double-click on that and show us the configuration of the asset it highlights.

Comment: on Detail Prefab it refers to the Texture 2D, not to a prefab

Comment: @anderlaini The grass material that is displayed on the ground (the last image in your post) isn't relevant.

Comment: Im running into the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @thijmendebrouwer didn't found solution =(